# Facebook like button iframe code not showing

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have just started to create a new website, which is currently not on the internet. My very first website so everything is new to me. I'm trying to implement the Facebook like button. I have inputted the code but nothing is being displayed. I am using TextWrangler to create the website and using MacBook Air. Not sure if this information will help. Perhaps it's not working because of the meta properties? I didn't quite understand what information I needed to input there.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>[]</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The []" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="file:///Users/[]/Documents/Sites/IBS.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://[].jpeg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The []" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="218100060" />
</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
<iframe   src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.phphref=file%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fshikhaverma%2FDocuments%2FSites%2FIBS.html&amp;
send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=arial&amp;
colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:40px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can help I would greatly appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like things are being double escaped?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code you provided is double escaped.
Which means that they are "&amp"s everywhere in the iFrame URL (src) code you provided:

```
//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.phphref=file%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fshikhaverma%2FDocuments%2FSites%2FIBS.html&amp;
send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=arial&amp;
colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80
```

Try pasting the url in your web browser, and it won't work, because it's so mal-formed.

Besides, Facebook like button can't use a local url to like, (in this case you used file:///Users/shikhaverma/Documents/Sites/IBS.html. ).
It has to be using an online, functioning URL. So for now, just enter any random URL of an online website untill you get your site hosted online.

I un-escaped the url, and it's still mal-formed. It should be "like.php?href=file" instead of "like.phphref=file". Why don't you just go back to Facebook and re-generate the code.

Also, is there a problem with your code editor? Why is everything getting double-escaped?

**Edit:** By the way, you can always utilize the unescape() JavaScript command to unescape text. More [here on Mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FFunctions#escape_and_unescape_functions).

Comment: No `http://` doesn't matter.  `//` is just a URL relative to the protocol.  Perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I re-gained the code from Facebook developers but this time put in a legit URL. However, this also did not work. I then decided to try to remove the &amps, however this did not work as well. I know, I'm not very tech savvy. But if there is perhaps another solution I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Not sure how this happened. In my actually code it is like.php?href=file. Must have pasted funny when I typed up the question. [I un-escaped the url, and it's still mal-formed. It should be "like.php?href=file" instead of "like.phphref=file". Why don't you just go back to Facebook and re-generate the code.  ]

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow. Ok, so I went back to Facebook and re-generated the code with an actual URL as advised. The code is as follows <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fshikzblog.blogspot.com.au&amp;etc...   Unfortunately it is still not displaying. I did put a border around it and only the border appears, but nothing else :(

Comment: @ShikhaVerma Can you paste the whole newly generated code in a comment here?

Comment: Sure :) <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.au&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: @SkikhaVerma It looks fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yp2Yq/ . What exactly happens when you run the code on your computer?

Comment: The code I just provided came directly from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: When I run it I can tell that something is there but it's all invisible

Comment: @ShikhaVerma How/where do you run it? Look here: jsfiddle.net/yp2Yq .

Comment: I run it on Safari locally. And use TextWrangler as my code editor.

Comment: Yeah, saw it on jsfiddle. Works there :) but not on my local website :(

Comment: Weird! Can you post the full code of your site (the page where the like button is) online somewhere? Like on jsfiddle?

Comment: How odd. The exact same code is working fine is jsfiddle. Maybe my website needs to actually be on the internet for it to work? Is that possible? http://jsfiddle.net/yp2Yq/

Comment: @ShikhaVerma No, it should work locally. Do you mind posting the whole code of your page (not only the like button, the whole page) on jsfiddle.net? Maybe some other code in there is interfering...

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/yp2Yq/2/... It's not the full code but this code still doesn't display the facebook like button on my computer. Works fine in jsfiddle though.

Comment: @ShikhaVerma Very strange that it doesn't work locally. Since it only works online, and not locally, I can maybe share some of my server space and add you as an FTP user on my server while your still developing your website. That way, you'd be able to develop your website, and you could test your code, on my server. Or do you have a server already? Tell me if this setup could help you in any way.

Comment: Ok, just tried my website on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/eXgWc/1/  Facebook like button is popping up there as well. Yeah maybe it is because I'm not connected to a server. Lol, I'm not even up to that point, connecting to a server. Don't know where to start with that yet. That's very kind of you to offer some server space :) Don't know how to connect though lol.

Comment: @ShikhaVerma You connect by downloading an FTP client like Firezilla (http://filezilla-project.org/), and enter your server FTP username and password to upload your pages on a server. I could create a FTP user on my server for you to test your site, and I could email the password and username to you (to do that I'd have to know your email address). BTW nice looking website.

Comment: Thank you :) jsfiddle wasn't showing my website properly cause it's lacking images etc, but yeah, thank you :) Ok, cool, just a quick question, if my website goes on your server would I still have ownership over it? Just want to be a little cautious, lol :P Very new at this stuff.

Comment: Wow great thank you :) Can give it a go :) My email is sverma330@gmail.com   I'll download the FTP client. Thank you again :)

Comment: @ShikhaVerma Yes you would have 100% percentage ownership of the content/site. I would just own the domain name/server. Besides when your finished the development stages you could delete your site from my server and host on your own domain name and server. I'm just offering this as a short-term solution, while your undergoing development.

Comment: @ShikhaVerma Okay, email sent!